# How to load specific rule (.drl) from Guvnor web-app?

Tags: drools, rule-engine

For example, I have added two rules (rule1.drl and rule2.drl) in Guvnor.

Normally I can retrieve those rules combined by creating a changeset.xml like:

```
<change-set ...>
<add>
<resource source='http://localhost/guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/name/LATEST.drl' type='DRL' basicAuthentication="enabled" username="username" password="password"  />
</add>
</change-set>
```

And load the changeset.xml by codes:

```
KnowledgeAgent kagent = KnowledgeAgentFactory.newKnowledgeAgent("Test Agent", kaconf);
kagent.applyChangeSet(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("changeset.xml"));
knowledgeBase = kagent.getKnowledgeBase();
```

But how I can retrieve specific rule only? e.g. rule2.drl

Of course I can change the url in changeset.xml to

```
<resource source='http://localhost/guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/name/LATEST/rule2.drl' type='DRL' basicAuthentication="enabled" username="username" password="password"  />
```

But I found that the response file miss the package name and all the import statements, for example:

```
package com.packname;
import namespace.EntityA;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround to this problem is to create two different packages, one for rule1.drl and one for rule2.drl. So my program read these two rule by two different changeset.

Answer (score 2):

When we need to execute especific drl package we use diferent changeset for each package/snapshot.

If the rules are related use different pojos for separate the rule, because you know the guvnor compile all your rules from a package in one big .drl, this could be slow if you have a hundred of rule-then-end's and iterate it with different pojo instances.

Answer (score 1):

The URL patterns for packages and individual assets is different. For assets (e.g. DRLs) the pattern is:

```xml
<resource source='http://localhost:9090/drools-guvnor/rest/packages/test/assets/MyRule/source' type='DRL' />
```